# Ubuntu doesn't see my phone (Sony Xperia Tipo)

Tags: 12.04, usb, android, sony

When I connect my phone Xperia Tipo to my Ubuntu 12.04, the USB icon does not appear in a launcher.

`lsusb` gives me following results:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2880 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0fce:5170 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB
```

I installed Wammu and it does not see phone either:

```
Wammu is now searching for phone:
All finished, found 0 phones
No phone has been found!
```

On the phone I have debbugging turned on and it sees Ubuntu.

Can I ask for instruction step by step? I am a begginer on Ubuntu.

Comment: did you set the phone to "mass storage mode"?

Comment: I have the same problem now: I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I try to connect it with Sony Xperia Z2 (which has Android 4.4). I have set Mass Storage Mode(MSC) setting but nothing happens when I connect cell phone to the laptop.
Please advise what else I can do/ Thanks!

Comment: The 'Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB' is the Xperia, I think.

Answer (score 6):

select USB Connection Mode,then choose : Mass Storage Mode(MSC)

take a look for this step by step [solution](http://akovid.blogspot.com/2012/08/solution-for-phone-memory-card-not.html)

it worked for me

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

In your Xperia go to :

1. Settings > Xperia > usb connectivity > usb connection mode
2. Select Mass storage mode (MSC) > Press OK
3. Then plug your phone with your SDCARD inside

Thats it.

Comment: this doesn't work for me using a Xperia Z (C6603) running stock Android 4.4.4. `lsusb` doesn't see the phone (confirmed the usb port and cable are working, tried alternate cable); the phone charges from this port and cable. Neither MSC nor MTM work.

Comment: Some cables are power only - not data. A cable charging the phone does not necessarily mean it can be used to connect to computer.

Comment: @Frumbert do you still have a problem? Show the output of your lsusb? My Xperia wouldn't mount automatically - Ubuntu 14.04.1 - but manual mounting worked. More details here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52932/linux-fails-to-mount-android-device-in-usb-msc-mode/52958#52958

Comment: @gaoithe: http://pastebin.com/LyAvzQti. Nothing works for me. Ubuntu fails to recognise the device electronically. Works well on Windows 7, works occasionally on MacOS 10.10.

Comment: @Frumbert. Anything seen in 'dmesg' also 'lsusb' when you plug in?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to comeup in google when searching for similar issue related to Xperia C4.

I noticed that the USB mass storage work when connected to the laptop directly and not when connected via the docking station. Here I have a dell laptop setup, with a fairly recent docking station.